# Contenedor div CSS no se redimensiona bien al añadir contenido

Tags: html, css

Tengo un web donde hay un contenedor principal con varias pestañas donde van mostrando contenido. Ese contenedor esta centrado. El problema es que al añadir mas contenido por así decirlo se acaba desbordando, es decir el contenido se sale del contenedor. La idea es que al ir añadiendo mas contenido simplemente el contenedor se va ajustando verticalmente.

Web:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Web con el contenido "desbordado":[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

CSS del contenedor:

```
.myContainer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #ffff;

  padding: 0;

  width: 70%;
  height: 80%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="myContainer">
  <app-profile-links></app-profile-links> <!-- Links -->
  <router-outlet></router-outlet> <!-- Contenido de cada pestaña-->
</div>
```

No se si es suficiente con esto. Si alguien necesita algo más que me lo digo y se lo paso.

Me pasa esto con todas las pestañas no solo con esta. He probado otras propiedades CSScomo min-height y sigue pasando lo mismo.

Si alguien me puede ayudar estaría muy agradecido :))) soy un total novato en CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Propiedad Overflow en Css

Lo que hace esta propiedad es precisamente controlar ese fenómeno que te esta ocurriendo, por lo que necesitarás agregar **`overflow: auto;`**  al contenedor de tus tablas, si no funciona, puede que necesites también fijar una altura al contenedor de las tabla.

puedes saber mas sobre esta propiedad [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)

Comment: Perfecto ahora ya me funciona. Muchas gracias!!